# Не получается создать свой первый проект на Django. Выдает ошибку (см. скриншот): syntax error can use starred expression only as assignment target

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Новичок в теме.
Операционная система: Windows XP. Язык разработки Python 3.4.4.
Установил Django командой  pip install Django - вроде успешно.
Потом создал папку (s), дал команду django-admin startproject prom - и вот что получилось (см. скриншот).
Что делать? В чем проблема? Не пойму.
[image: django-admin startproject project_name]

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/windows/

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/

Comment: А какая версия django у Вас?